# react native : React packager ready. ERROR Watcher took too long to load

Tags: android, react-native, watchman

im trying to run an android project on react native but when im trying to run it using this command : `react-native start` then it will leave me with this error :

```
Looking for JS files in
   C:\Users\mohammad\Desktop\AwsoneProject

[2:55:39 AM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[2:55:40 AM] <START> Crawling File System
[2:55:40 AM] <START> Loading bundles layout
[2:55:40 AM] <END>   Loading bundles layout (1ms)

React packager ready.

 ERROR  Watcher took too long to load
Try running `watchman version` from your terminal
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html
Error: Watcher took too long to load
Try running `watchman version` from your terminal
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html
    at [object Object]._onTimeout (index.js:103:16)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

See http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html
for common problems and solutions.
```

i've search the net but after hours i still cant fix it .
i have to mention that im using windows in this case .
i'd appreciate any help .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually a Windows specific issue. It works fine on Linux for me. Increase the **MAX_WAIT_TIME** in the FileWatcher. It's actually timing out.

Have a check at [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.34-stable/packager/react-packager/src/node-haste/FileWatcher/index.js#L16)

You have to increase this:

```
const MAX_WAIT_TIME = 120000;
```

Comment: how long do we have to wait?

Comment: No issues. Just use the `MAX_WAIT_TIME` property. It should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase increase the timeout in FileWatcher - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linux-windows-support.html#content